# Building a community forum with Twitter Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, frameworks, forums

I'd like to build my own community forums with Twitter Bootstrap framework. Does anyone have any tips for me? I really have no idea where to start.

Comment: This is too vague, start with bootstrap :) Can you explain better: build my own community forums?

Comment: @Unykvis My aim is to build a nice & sleek forum using the Twitter-Bootstrap framework. So far I've only dealt with CSS & HTML, but I've heard that PHP knowledge is needed.

Comment: Yes, why don't you try to use an open source platform: http://www.discourse.org/

Comment: NodeBB (http://www.nodebb.org) is open source and their default theme framework uses Bootstrap

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here you can start with: <kbd>[Create a Forum from Scratch Tutorial](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/how-to-create-a-phpmysql-powered-forum-from-scratch/)</kbd>

Comment: i sure wish someone made a tutorial with mysqli or pdo instead of mysql. it would sure help noobs learn(but then you all wouldn't have anything to do if we learned to program all by our selves)